# How can I make my javascript slider more responsive (faster)?

Tags: javascript

This is my first project in Javascript. It's an image slider with a next and previous arrow. One thing really bothering me is that there can some very noticeable lag between clicking an arrow and the image actually changing.

I'd really appreciate if someone review my code and let me know what I could do better.

http://jsfiddle.net/afptfbs8/40/

```
var myImage = document.getElementById("mainImage");
var imageArray = ["http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/", "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2/", "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/3/", "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/4/"];
var imageIndex = 0;
var prevImage = document.getElementById("prev");
var nextImage = document.getElementById("next");
var myTime = 3000;
var myInterval = setInterval(changeImage, myTime);                      

function changeImage() {
    imageIndex++;
    if (imageIndex >= imageArray.length) {
        imageIndex = 0;
    }
    myImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
}

prevImage.onclick = function() {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    myInterval = setInterval(changeImage, myTime);
    if (imageIndex === 0) {
        imageIndex = imageArray.length -1;
    } else {
        imageIndex = imageIndex - 1;
    }
    myImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);

};

nextImage.onclick = function() {
    clearInterval(myInterval);
    myInterval = setInterval(changeImage, myTime);
    if (imageIndex === imageArray.length -1) {
        imageIndex = 0;
    } else {
        imageIndex = imageIndex + 1;
    }
    myImage.setAttribute("src", imageArray[imageIndex]);
};

imageArray.forEach(function (value, index) {
    var node = document.createElement("li");
    var textNode = document.createTextNode(index);
    node.appendChild(textNode);
    document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(node);
});


myInterval
```

Comment: i'd suggest you to put your image in your file directory, not online, 'cause it will take more time to load if its accessing the internet. You download all the images and specify the link of your image using the src

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that each time you change the picture, you are refetching it from the server. Take a look at the network panel to see. I suggest preloading all of the images so that they do not need to be refetched every time.

```
var images = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
    images[i] = new Image();
    images[i].src = imageArray[i];
}
```